# Something (very) simple is wrong with my installation of R Studio/Shiny Apps

Tags: r, statistics, data-visualization, shiny

I've discovered this wonderful list of Shiny App tutorials: https://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#inputs-and-outputs

I'm trying to run the second one, which should see a plot come out of the data. Instead, all I get is a blank screen (still not enough "points" on stack overflow to post images ...)

I don't understand, since my code for the UI is:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  headerPanel("Miles Per Gallon: Wednesday, 6 August"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of observations
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("variable", "Variable:", 
                list("Cylinders" = "cyl", 
                     "Transmission" = "am", 
                     "Gears" = "gear")), 

    checkboxInput("outliers", "Show Outliers", FALSE)
  ),

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    h3(textOutput("caption")), 

    plotOutput("mpgPlot")
  )
))
```

...and my code for the server is:

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)

mpgData <- mtcars
mpgData$am <- factor(mpgData$am, labels = c("Automatic", "Manual"))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

#Create the formula text as a "reactive" 
  formulaText <- reactive({
    paste("mpg ~", input$variable)
  })

#Print the formulaText as a caption 
  output$caption <-renderText({formulaText()})
#Plot the requested variable against the mpg 

output$mpgPlot <- renderPlot({
  boxplot(as.formula(formulaText())), 
  data = mpgData, 
  outline = input$outliers
})

})
```

This is so frustrating because there is nothing to it, supposedly, but it just doesn't work.

I should point out that I'm running R-Studio 0.98 on Linux Mint Petra.

Comment: Okay, okay, I've figured this one out: it's just that in the line: boxplot(as.formula ...), I'd left the definition for data and outline outside of the first set of parentheses. What a frustrating thing though ...

Comment: Can you answer your own question and check it as an accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, okay, I've figured this one out: it's just that in the line. This is now "answered".